# What is the song that plays when the results of the failed transmutation are dug up?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

Does anyone know what's the name of the song that plays in FMA Brotherhood when Ed and Pinako dig up the corpse of the failed transmutation during rain?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESzkiDXlFkI) you can hear the song more clearly from the minute 9:25 to 10:03.

I can't find it on Shazam or on Youtube :(

Answer (score 4):

It's **FMA Brotherhood OST 2 - Anticipation**: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-W7xveVzUw) is a link to the full track.